# C++/CLI Intellisense doesn't work in Debug configuration

Tags: c++, c++-cli, intellisense

I have a C++/CLI project in Visual Studio 2012 with a strange Intellisense issue. I'm referencing an external native C++ library (the Intel MSDK) via headers. In Release, I can navigate to all these headers via F12, I get Intellisense on all the types I use and no Intellisense errors. But in Debug, it's as if it couldn't find the headers; I get hundreds of Intellisense errors and navigation using Go To Definition on those types is impossible.

Note that the project *compiles* fine in both Debug and Release, it's really the Intellisense that goes awry in Debug.

The include paths are exactly the same in Debug and Release; they are based on the INTELMEDIASDKROOT environment variable.

What could the problem be?

Comment: It never occurred to you that "hundreds of IntelliSense errors" might have something to do with navigation not working???  Nobody can see them but you.

Comment: Yes, that occured to me. Both have probably the same cause. What is the cause is the question I'm asking. The Intellisense errors state that it doesn't know about the Intel MSDK types, as I suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried cleaning up all temporary files including .suo, restarting Visual Studio, no dice.

I ended up checking in all my modifications to source control, deleted the project folder and redownloaded everything. Lo and behold, Intellisense and navigation work in Debug. Perhaps I'll never know what that was. Corrupt Intellisense database perhaps?